# Is it possible to set GRUB to refuse to boot at night?

Tags: grub

I often overwork myself, in the sense that nothing can make me stop coding or reading papers and other resources on the internet. I stay up all night doing that, and the day after, I simply feel terrible due to lack of sleep. Even if I don't stay up all night, I often stay up until very late and still get very little sleep.

So, I was wondering if there is a way to make GRUB simply refuse to boot after a set time in the evening, and keep having this behavior until early in the morning. I did a few searches, but it seems like nobody else on the internet has ever felt the need of doing this.

Comment: The root of the problem is not technical, and as such is not solvable by purely technical means - I guess you might start keeping your computer powered on, to avoid boot issues. If you want to go the technical way, how about a check in your login script?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's something which GRUB is able to do. You might want to try an alternative, for example, a combination of http://linuxers.org/article/gnome-nanny-parental-control-system-linux and http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/116324.